# Rails where do global variables go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning alot about the DRY concept in Rails so here's my question:

I have a fixed sidebar in my application that always needs to load various Objects, such as `Locations`.

In the controller related to my `index` page, actually in `controllers/pages_controller.rb` I'm loading `@locations`:

```
@company = current_user.company

@locations = if @company
   current_user.company.locations.order(:name)
else
   []
end
```

Which works fine for my navigation menu (sidebar), however, once I select a location and load a view delegated from a different controller (in this case `locations/show.html.erb`) my `@locations` variable is no longer found.

Sure, I could add it to the `show` method in my `locations_controller.rb` file, but that isn't very DRY considering I'd have to put the above code in every single controller method that relies on the sidebar navigation menu (all of them!) since it's fixed.

What's the DRY way to do this once and not have to do it in every controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method in your `application_controller`

```
def set_locations
....
end
```

Then in your `pages_controller` and `locations_controller` add a `before_filter`

```
before_filter :set_locations
```

It will set call set location before all all methods of the pages and locations controller.

If you want to set locations only for few controller actions then call:

```
before_filter :set_locations,:only=>[:show,:index, :your_action_name]
```

**Updated:**

In Rails 5 `before_filter` is deprecated and you can use `before_action`

Comment: **Just as a note:** for Rails 5 use `before_action` callbacks instead, as `before_filter` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

You could add it to the ApplicationController in a method that runs before every action, every controller inherits from this ApplicationController so it will be available.